# Javascript/SparkAR — How to access a null object inside a plane tracker using script?

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I am trying to access a null object inside a plane tracker located in the Scene without success. I believe the issue is the hierarchy of the scene but, I need the plane tracker to be outside the Device (screenshot for reference). Any help is really appreciated.

Here's the scene setup:
[Screenshot](https://share.getcloudapp.com/p9uN425k)

[Error] Warning: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Property 'obj0' doesn't exist

Code:

```
const Scene = require('Scene');

(async function () {
  const allObjs = ([
    obj0,
  ] = await Promise.all([
    Scene.root.findFirst('obj0'),
  ]));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are retrieving `obj0` asynchronously, meaning you cannot expect it to be available in the next line but only once the async call has finished.

To ensure `obj0` is available, either use `Promise.then` as in

```
Scene.root.findFirst('obj0').then(obj0 => {
    // obj0 is available here
});
```

or `await` it synchronously as in

```
const obj0 = await Scene.root.findFirst('obj0');
// obj0 is available
```